# Need your help understanding java programming concept

Tags: java, class, object, memory, memory-management

```
public class Concept {    
    int num;    
    public static void main(String args[])    
    {    
        Concept obj1=new Concept();    
        Concept obj2=obj1;    
        obj1.num=100;    
        obj2.num=200;    
        System.out.println(obj1.num);    
        System.out.println(obj2.num);    
        //obj1.num=null;    

        obj2.num=500;    

        System.out.println(obj1.num);    
        System.out.println(obj2.num);    
    }   

}
```

Here, this is simple java program.

Output is

```
200
200
500   
500
```

How does the memory allocation work here? And how can we set null as Obj1.num=null?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You ask two questions at once.

---

Java uses *references*, thus by setting `obj2 = obj1`, the values are **not copied**, both references refer to the same object. Setting the value of `num` through `obj1` is the same as setting it through `obj2`.

In memory it looks like:

```
        +-----------------+
obj2 -> |  Concept        | <- obj1
        +-----+-----+-----+
        | num | int | 200 |
        +-----+-----+-----+
```

If you would however use the following code, two objects would be constructed:

```
Concept obj1 = new Concept();
obj1.num = 200;
Concept obj2 = new Concept();
obj2.num = 300;
```

Then the memory would look like:

```
        +-----------------+         +-----------------+
obj1 -> |  Concept        | obj2 -> |  Concept        |
        +-----+-----+-----+         +-----+-----+-----+
        | num | int | 200 |         | num | int | 300 |
        +-----+-----+-----+         +-----+-----+-----+
```

Thus modifying `num` from `obj1` would set a different part of the memory than from `obj2`.

---

You cannot assign `null` to an `int`: it's a primitive type. If you want an integer with a `null` value, try `Integer`.

Answer (score 7):

`obj2` has the same reference of `obj1`, so modifying the state of any of these will be reflected in both variables since they're *pointing* to the same reference.

Here's a picture to explain the behavior of object references (explained in this case using `Person` class):

[image]

<sub>Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7034719/1065197</sub>

Note that you cannot nullify an `int` nor any primitive value in Java, so `obj1.num = null` is invalid. However, if you declare `num` as `Integer` you can set its value as `null` since `Integer` is a **wrapper class** for the primitive `int`.

Answer (score 3):

Java is not C++,

```
Concept obj1=new Concept();    
Concept obj2=obj1; // obj2 is a reference to obj1.
```

I think you wanted,

```
Concept obj1=new Concept();    
Concept obj2=new Concept();
```

Also, you can't set a primitive type (like `int`) to null. You could set an `Integer` wrapper to null,

```
Concept {    
 // int num;
 Integer num = null;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't, because you are declaring `num` as an `int`, which is a *primitive type*.

**What can you do?**
You can use its [**wrapper class**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberclasses.html) `Integer`:

```
Integer num;
...
num = null; // valid since num is now an object
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Concept {    
    int num;    
    public static void main(String args[])    
    {    
        Concept obj1=new Concept();    // Only one Concept object created. The reference obj1 is pointing to it.
        Concept obj2=obj1;    // now 2 references obj1 and obj2 are pointing to the same object.
        obj1.num=100;    // since both references are pointing to the same object, the changes they make will be on the `same` object
        obj2.num=200;    
        System.out.println(obj1.num);    
        System.out.println(obj2.num);    
        //obj1.num=null;    

        obj2.num=500;    

        System.out.println(obj1.num);    
        System.out.println(obj2.num);    
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Obj1.num=null;
```

num cannot be set to null because num is a primitive int, not an object.  In Java only object references may be set to null.

As for the memory handling.  I have annotated your code below to explain what is happening.

```
public class Concept {    
    int num;    
    public static void main(String args[])    
    {    
        Concept obj1=new Concept();      // A new object is created.  Ref stored in obj1
        Concept obj2=obj1;               // The ref from obj1 is copied to obj2
        obj1.num=100;                    // obj1 and obj2 now hold the same ref to the same object
        obj2.num=200;                    // overwrites previous assignment; the java compiler is likely to strip out the previous line as it is redundant
        System.out.println(obj1.num);    
        System.out.println(obj2.num);    
        //obj1.num=null;    

        obj2.num=500;                    // as before

        System.out.println(obj1.num);    
        System.out.println(obj2.num);    
    }   

}
```

It is worth noting, that Java, unlike some other languages always creates its objects on the heap.  A region of memory that is under its management, and it garbage collects for us.  It does not create objects on the stack, thus fields and variables of type Object are always references to the object.

Comment: +1 for the *single line comments*